# Lived vs Lived out

Tags: american-english, past-tense

I am writing the backstory of my character in my short story. I can't figure out which to use between these two and what the difference is between them. Please help.

> Marcus **lived** his entire childhood with his father in Hanover, MN.

or

> Marcus **lived out** his entire childhood with his father in Hanover,
> MN.

Answer (score 5):

***Lived*** is just fine.

***Lived out*** is used more appropriately when the end of a person's life is in view.

> [He lived out (the final years of) his life in quiet retirement.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22lived%22versus%20%22lived%20out%22)

*Lived out* could also be used in place of *to do* or *to experience*, as in

> [He has finally had the chance to live out his dreams/fantasies.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22lived%22versus%20%22lived%20out%22)